# Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString to string?

Tags: haskell

Trying to write a module which returns the external IP address of my computer.
Using `Network.Wreq` `get` function, then applying a lense to obtain `responseBody`, the type I end up with is `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString`. As I want to filter out the trailing "\n" of the result body, I want to use this for a regular expression subsequently.
Problem: That seemingly very specific ByteString type is not accepted by regex library and I found no way to convert it to a `String`.

Here is my feeble attempt so far (not compiling).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module ExtIp (getExtIp) where
import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens
import Data.BytesString.Lazy
import Text.Regex.Posix

getExtIp :: IO String
getExtIp = do
    r <- get "http://myexternalip.com/raw"
    let body = r ^. responseBody
    let addr = body =~ "[^\n]*\n"
    return (addr)
```

So my question is obviously: How to convert that funny special ByteString to a `String`? Explaining how I can approach such a problem myself is also appreciated. I tried to use `unpack` and `toString` but have no idea what to import to get those functions if they exist.

Being a very sporadic haskell user, I also wonder if someone could show me the idiomatic haskell way of defining such a function. The version I show here does not account for possible runtime errors/exceptions, after all.

Comment: I think it is overkill to use regex in this case and go for a version that still uses `ByteString` you can implement something like `trim` trim easily with `Data.Char.isSpace` and `dropWhile` and `reverse`.

Comment: to get an idea where you find functions - use goo… uhm no - [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isspace)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe So in my case, given I already imported ``Data.ByteString.Lazy`` it would be ``let body = Char8.unpack (r ^. responseBody)``? For me it yields: extip.hs:6:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Data.BytesString.Lazy'
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.ByteString.Lazy (from bytestring-0.10.8.1)
      Data.ByteString.Lens (from lens-4.14)
      Data.ByteString.Char8 (from bytestring-0.10.8.1)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: typo in import statement ("BytesString" -> "ByteString") - starts to look a bit better by now.

Comment: What a mess lol. Now I get: ``ghci> :t (unpack (r ^. responseBody))`` ->
``(unpack (r ^. responseBody)) :: [GHC.Word.Word8]`` Still not a String.

Comment: `ByteString` is made of bytes, not characters! There's some module in the package that helps fake it a bit, but I think only for strict bytestrings.

Comment: terrible situation on the string front. module system so needed here..

Comment: @nicolas One would think a string specific type class could sort out the mess but no one ever bothered to write one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I simply do not understand why you insist on using `String`s, when you have already a `ByteString` at hand that is the faster/more efficient implementation.
Importing `regex` gives you almost no benefit - for parsing an ip-address I would use `attoparsec` which works great with `ByteString`s.

Here is a version that does not use regex but returns a String - note I did not compile it for I have no haskell setup where I am right now.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module ExtIp (getExtIp) where
import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as Char8
import Data.Char (isSpace)

getExtIp :: IO String
getExtIp = do
    r <- get "http://myexternalip.com/raw"
    return $ Char8.unpack $ trim (r ^. responseBody)
  where trim = Char8.reverse . (Char8.dropWhile isSpace) . Char8.reverse . (Char8.dropWhile isSpace)
```

Comment: What I want is to return a canonical type which does not produce extra work (such as this SO question here). Had Wreq returned String I would not have the trouble I am facing. If the language has no canonical string type, whenever libraries are used, such conversion problems arise. Call me old fashioned...but I prefer to stick to one canonical type at interface boundaries.

Comment: extip.hs:14:41: error:
    * Couldn't match type `GHC.Word.Word8' with `Char'
      Expected type: GHC.Word.Word8 -> Bool
        Actual type: Char -> Bool
    * In the first argument of `B.dropWhile', namely `isSpace'
      In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(B.dropWhile isSpace)'
      In the second argument of `(.)', namely
        `(B.dropWhile isSpace) . Char8.reverse . (B.dropWhile isSpace)'
...

Comment: I think I fixed it - have no ghc at hand (as I already said).

Answer (score 19):

Short answer: Use [`unpack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v:unpack) from Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8

Longer answer:

In general when you want to convert a ByteString (of any variety) to a String or Text you have to specify an encoding - e.g. UTF-8 or Latin1, etc.

When retrieving an HTML page the encoding you are suppose to use may appear in the Content-type header or in the response body itself as a `<meta ...>` tag.

Alternatively you can just guess at what the encoding of the body is.

In your case I presume you are accessing a site like http://whatsmyip.org and you only need to parse out your IP address. So without examining the headers or looking through the HTML, a safe encoding to use would be Latin1.

To convert ByteStrings to Text via an encoding, have a look at the functions in [Data.Text.Encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html)

For instance, the `decodeLatin1` function.

Comment: Given: ``let b1 = r ^. responseBody``, ``decodeLatin1 b1`` yields: <interactive>:119:14: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Data.ByteString.ByteString'
                  with actual type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString'
      NB: `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString'
            is defined in `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal'
          `Data.ByteString.ByteString'
            is defined in `Data.ByteString.Internal'
    * In the first argument of `decodeLatin1', namely `b1'
      In the expression: decodeLatin1 b1
      In an equation for `it': it = decodeLatin1 b1

Comment: It's not easy to see from the docs, but decodeLatin1 requires a _strict_ ByteString. Use `toStrict` to convert the lazy string first.