# Clumsy Looking Type Signature for ByteStrings in Haskell HTTP Response

Tags: haskell, bytestring, http-conduit

I'm experimenting with the http-conduit library and have this simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-7.12
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package http-conduit
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal

getUrl :: IO (Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString) ---eeew!
getUrl = do
  resp <- simpleHttp "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  return resp
```

I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571939/data-bytestring-lazy-internal-bytestring-to-string) that I should prefer a response as a ByteString to a [Char] or String. I assumed the OverloadedStrings pragma might make this less of an issue, but doesn't appear to change with respect to my out-type.

The function works fine and dutifully prints out a simple http response for the homepage of SO, but that type signature looks really ugly:

```
getUrl :: IO (Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
```

And I have to say I see very few things like that from internet examples (we've got more dots than an elliptical Java import, man).  Is that right?  If I want to return a reponse and then start parsing on it, say with HXT or tagsoup or attoparsec, is this the right approach or type signature?

I notice, for example, this gets even uglier when I start to add the ability to take arguments, such as supplying a different URL:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal

-- alright, first arg is now string for my url...
getUrl :: String -> IO (Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
getUrl url = do
  resp <- simpleHttp url
  return resp


main :: IO (ByteString)  -- what?!  inside the () ?
main = do
  getUrl "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

This seems unwholesome.  How should I understand how to structure this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write types with their qualified path. However, as you've already imported `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal` and unless you have some other `ByteString` type in scope (like the strict one) you can simply omit the `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal`:

```
getUrl :: IO ByteString
```

Also, unless you have some particular need to import `Internal`, I recommend you just import `Data.ByteString.Lazy` (which also exports the lazy `ByteString` type you are using). If you have both strict and lazy `ByteString` in scope, I'd import them qualified:

```
 import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
```

Then `BS.ByteString` is the strict type and `BL.ByteString` the lazy one - no need to write out the full `Data.ByteString.ByteString` or `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`.

It is also worth mentioning (thanks @duplode) that either of the bytestring modules is usually best imported qualified since they defines a whole bunch of functions that clash with the Prelude (and with each other).

Finally, note that parens around a type by itself does nothing. `(ByteString)` and `ByteString` are identical. As such, I would not include them.

---

Unrelated to your question, but some remarks on your monadic code:

- Every time you write something like

  ```
  do x <- e
     return x
  ```

  it can be replace with just `e`.
- Every time you write something like

  ```
  do e
  ```

  it can be replaced with `e`.

Comment: As a footnote, it is worth mentioning that importing the bytestring modules qualified is also useful to avoid name clashes with `Prelude` stuff such as `map` or `readFile`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alec.  Couple things trying to work this.  If I do the import as only import Data.ByteString, it does not seem to match:     
`• Couldn't match type ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
                     with ‘ByteString’`

Comment: And (2), what am I doing wrong in trying to make my monads match your comments on that?  I'm trying:

`getUrl :: String -> ByteString
getUrl = do simpleHttp url
`

And I get:     

`Variable not in scope: url :: String`

Comment: @Mittenchops For your first comment - that's my bad (I've fixed the answer). You need to import `Data.ByteString.Lazy` not just `Data.ByteString` (you need the lazy, not strict version). As to the second: `getUrl url = simpleHttp url` is enough, and `main = getUrl "https://www.stackoverflow.com"` is enough.