# Haskell function rewrite without bind return

Tags: haskell, pointfree

On advice I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093163/1052117), I am trying to rewrite a function without an extraneous bind assignment and return, but am getting stuck with an extra IO I can't seem to understand how to get out of it.

I have

```
good :: IO (Either Int String)

getit :: Either Int String -> Int

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- fmap getit good
  putStrLn $ show x
```

main works fine.  But....

```
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
  putStrLn $ show $ fmap getit good

-- let's try totally without do
main3 :: IO ()
main3 = putStrLn $ fmap show $ fmap getit good
```

main2 fails with:

```
• No instance for (Show (IO Int)) arising from a use of ‘show’
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘show $ fmap getit good’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ show $ fmap getit good
  In the expression: do { putStrLn $ show $ fmap getit good }
```

And main3 fails with:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: IO String
```

What's the correct way to rewrite this idiomatically?

(Sub-question: is "<-" this guy actually called a bind?  via here: [Are there pronounceable names for common Haskell operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894/are-there-pronounceable-names-for-common-haskell-operators) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable-binding in `do`-notation desugars into calls to the *bind* combinator `>>=`:

```
do { x <- m ; rest }  =  m >>= \x -> do rest
```

So your example translates to:

```
main = fmap getit good >>= \x -> putStrLn $ show x
```

Or, in point-free style:

```
main = fmap getit good >>= putStrLn . show
```

Or, exploiting the relationship between `fmap` and `>>=`:

```
main = good >>= putStrLn . show . getit
```

For many monads this last form will be more efficient. `fmap` often has to rebuild the mapped structure (for example, lists' `fmap` runs in O(n) time) whereas function composition is always O(1).

Comment: And, `print = putStrLn . show`, so `main = good >>= print . getit`

Answer (score 2):

Self, as you googled for how to pronounce "<-" you discovered that I think you were looking for:

```
main4 :: IO ()
main4 = (fmap show $ fmap getit good) >>= putStrLn
```

From here:

https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside

> A more complex example involves the binding of variables using "<-":
>
> main = do a <- readLn
>             print a This code is desugared into:
>
> main = readLn
>         `>>=` (\a -> print a)

But @Benjamin Hodgson's answer is better, especially the version that requires no fmaps at all.

And to the subquestion, "<-" desugars to a bind, but is pronounced "is drawn from" via: https://wiki.haskell.org/Pronunciation